# Nested CASE statements in SQL

Tags: sql, nested

I am running the below SQL and I need to add a case statement for the svcState column.

I have a value defined for each number in that column which I need to have in my query. For instance 7 is OK, 4 is down etc. I tried adding this in the CASE statement as below and it seems, the syntax is incorrect. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
A.NodeName AS NodeName,
MAX(CASE WHEN Poller_Name='svcServiceName' THEN CAST(Status AS varchar) ELSE ''END) svcServiceName,
MAX(CASE (CASE WHEN Poller_Name='svcState' AND Status ='7' THEN  'OK'
         WHEN Poller_Name='svcstate' AND Status ='4' THEN 'OUT OF SERVICE' END) 
    THEN CAST(Status AS bigint) ELSE '' END) svcState
FROM
(
SELECT
Nodes.Caption AS NodeName, CustomNodePollers_CustomPollers.UniqueName AS Poller_Name, CustomNodePollerStatus_CustomPollerStatus.Status AS Status, CustomNodePollerStatus_CustomPollerStatus.rowid as row, CustomNodePollerStatus_CustomPollerStatus.RawStatus as RawStatus
FROM
((Nodes INNER JOIN CustomPollerAssignment CustomNodePollerAssignment_CustomPollerAssignment ON (Nodes.NodeID = CustomNodePollerAssignment_CustomPollerAssignment.NodeID)) INNER JOIN CustomPollers CustomNodePollers_CustomPollers ON (CustomNodePollerAssignment_CustomPollerAssignment.CustomPollerID = CustomNodePollers_CustomPollers.CustomPollerID)) INNER JOIN CustomPollerStatus CustomNodePollerStatus_CustomPollerStatus ON (CustomNodePollerAssignment_CustomPollerAssignment.CustomPollerAssignmentID = CustomNodePollerStatus_CustomPollerStatus.CustomPollerAssignmentID)
WHERE 
(
(CustomNodePollers_CustomPollers.UniqueName = 'svcServiceName') OR
(CustomNodePollers_CustomPollers.UniqueName = 'svcState') 
)
AND
(
(CustomNodePollerAssignment_CustomPollerAssignment.InterfaceID = 0)
)
and Nodes.Caption = '101'
)A
GROUP BY NodeName, row
--ORDER BY svcServiceName
) B
```

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: You haven't put the strings "OK" or "DOWN" in your sql query anywhere, why do you expect it to give you that output?  Adding a 'State Code' table would make this a whole lot easier.

Comment: Your current output has both giving state 7, why should one be OK and one be DOWN?

Comment: Hi MatBailie, Yes that was just an example. It will be OK for both entries. There are other values which are not 7 and it will display different states.

Comment: Do you have a table that maps these state ID's to strings?  *(You should do, and if you do, just join on it in the outer query.)*

Comment: I have commented the section wherein I added a case Condition 1 and Condition 2, I am not sure how to display the status.

Comment: I don't have a Table unfortunately, I will have to do this in the sql itself.

Comment: "I tried adding this in the CASE statement as below". I don't see where you tried adding it.

Comment: CASE **EXPRESSION**, not statement.

Comment: Please mention your dbms

Comment: Using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Poller_Name = 'svcState' THEN (CASE WHEN status = '7' THEN 'OK' ELSE 'DOWN' END) END)
```

Or...

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Poller_Name = 'svcState' AND status = '7' THEN 'OK'
         WHEN Poller_Name = 'svcState' AND status = '4' THEN 'DOWN' END)
```

Or...

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Poller_Name != 'svcState' THEN NULL -- Assumes the poller_name is never NULL
         WHEN status       = '7'        THEN 'OK'
         WHEN status       = '4'        THEN 'DOWN'
    END)
```

Where there is no `ELSE` specified, it is implicitly `ELSE NULL`, and `NULL` values are skipped by the `MAX()`.

Comment: MatBilie, I updated my Original Post with the query I am now using based on your inputs. Still seeming some issues. It seems my case expression is incorrect.